# error on accessing attribute value in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am a JavaScript newbie and try to get a value of an custom attribute contained in a custom tag in pure JavaScript respectively check if the attribute exists.

The first button should test if the attribute exists in the span.

The second button should output the value of the attribute.

The error message I get on the console on both buttons is:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined
```

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>test</title>

</head>
<body>


<span id="foo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
<p/>
<span id="anotherfoo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick <baz><anothertag alternative="yellow">brown</anothertag> fox jumps over</baz> the lazy dog.</span>
<p/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="mysecondFunction()">Have a try with the second span</button>

<p id="anotherdemo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("anothertag")[0].getAttribute("alternative");
  console.log(x);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function mysecondFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("anotherfoo").getElementsByTagName("anothertag")[0].getAttribute("alternative"); 
  console.log(y);
  document.getElementById("anotherdemo").innerHTML = y;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anybody help and explain?
Thanks.

Comment: Two things: 1. `getElementById` is a method of `document`, not `document.body`. 2. `getElementByID` => `getElementById`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. So: `document.getElementById`.

Comment: not sure `getElemenById` apply to `document.body`... Think it should be call from `document` object

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post accordingly. The error message has changed

Answer (score 0):

In order to get:

1. The first button should test if the attribute exists in the span.
2. The second button should output the value of the attribute.

You could do something like the snippet below, in particular`myFunction()` should check if `x` exists, if so, does it have a `getAttribute("alternative")`? If yes, then it `exists`, otherwise it `doesn't exist`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document
    .getElementById("foo")
    .getElementsByTagName("anothertag")[0];
  let exists =
    x && x.getAttribute("alternative") ? `exists` : `doesn't exist`;
  console.log(exists);
  document.getElementById(
    "demo"
  ).innerHTML = `attribute "alternative" ${exists}`;
}

function mysecondFunction() {
  var y = document
    .getElementById("anotherfoo")
    .getElementsByTagName("anothertag")[0]
    .getAttribute("alternative");
  console.log(y);
  document.getElementById("anotherdemo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<span id="foo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
<p></p>
<span id="anotherfoo">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick <baz><anothertag alternative="yellow">brown</anothertag> fox jumps over</baz> the lazy dog.</span>
<p></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="mysecondFunction()">Have a try with the second span</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="anotherdemo"></p>
```

You would probably want to make the code above more bulletproof by, among other things, check first if `getElementById("foo")` exists, and only then check if there's a `getElementsByTagName("anothertag")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot: I was just wondering why the line "var x = document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("anothertag")[0].getAttribute("alternative");"  gave me this error. I had tested this with comparable examples form the web (w3schools and others) and it expectedly didn't work, but never produced an error

Comment: The `span` with id `"foo"` doesn't have any element with tag `anothertag`, that's why you're seeing that error and that's what my snippet above checks for you :)

Comment: You're never using the `span` with id `"anotherfoo"`